# Laravel 5 - проблема с ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Здравствуйте. Не могу создать работающий ajax запрос.
Вот мой код:
Кнопка:

```
 <input type="button" id='{{$contractor->id}}' value="Add to favorites" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addToFavourite(this.id)"/>
```

JS:

```
function addToFavourite(id) {

        var base_url = 'http://localhost:8000/'
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"add-to-favourite",
        cache: false,
        data: {'id': id}, // если нужно передать какие-то данные
        type: "POST", // устанавливаем типа запроса POST
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok')
        } //контент подгружается в div#content
    });
}
```

Роут:

```
Route::post('add-to-favourite', 'ContractorsPage@addToFavourite');
```

И контроллер:

```
class ContractorsPage extends Controller
  {
   public function addToFavourite(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $data = Input::all();
        print_r($data);
        die;
    }
    dd('ok');
   }
  }
```

С кнопки в js id передается, через алерт проверял, но дальше ajax запроса ничего не происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем я ошибся.

Ошибка где в url, так как дебаггер сообщает:

POST http://localhost:8000/add-to-favourite 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: В Developer Tools браузера пробовали смотреть ответ бекенда? Поделитесь и им.

Comment: @xEdelweiss , смотрел, ошибка 500. Был не правильный урл. Поменял на правильный,  все равно ошибка: POST http://localhost:8000/add-to-favourite 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: Включите отладку в Laravel и проверьте еще раз.

В 5й версии, надо выставить ``APP_DEBUG=true`` в файле ``.env``

Comment: Подозреваю, что у вас ошибка из-за отсутствия CSRF токена. Но стоит включить вывод ошибок и убедиться в этом.

Comment: @xEdelweiss debug включен, но вот только пользоваться дебаггером в laravel я не умею, с ним работаю совсем недавно.

Comment: Попробуйте тогда добавить csrf токен, либо отключить его проверку: [CSRF Protection](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как написали в комментарии, проблема с токеном. Решить можно так:

В head добавить

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
```

В функции передавать этот токен

```
function addToFavourite(id) {

        var base_url = 'http://localhost:8000/'
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"add-to-favourite",
        cache: false,
        data: {'id': id, '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok')
        } //контент подгружается в div#content
    });
}
```